# If two ring homomorphism have the same non-trivial Kernel and the codomain is finite are they the same homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

I don't really know how should I be thinking about this, because I think that this is true but I am not really sure.

Comment: It is extremely bad form to change your question to invalidate existing solutions. You should avoid that in the future, unless you come to some agreement with posters who have spent time answering your *original* question. It isn't fair to move the goalposts like that.  Another thing you should do is to always state the question in the body of the post.  It should not appear in the title alone.

Comment: Are you assuming they have the same codomain which is finite, or only assuming each homomorphism has a finite codomain?

Comment: Also the counterexamples in the existing answers can easily be modified to disprove your new conjecture. eg take $f$ from rschwieb's answer, and consider $g$ vs $fg$ where $g:F_q[x]\to F_q$ sends $x$ to zero.

Comment: @stewbasic I added my answer after the modifications were made, and I was referring to Tsemo's solution being the victim. My solution needs modification?!

Answer (score 3):

No, two isomorphisms are not necessarily equal and they have the same kernel.

Answer (score 2):

> If two ring homomorphism have the same non-trivial Kernel and the codomain is finite are they the same homomorphism?

No. For example, the [Frobenius automorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism) $f:F_q\to F_q$ can produce a map which is not the identity. Given a epimorphism $g:R\to F_q$ the map $g$ and the map $fg$ will have the same kernels and images, but they are unequal.